# Use xargs to send requests to the same server in parallel with netcat

Tags: linux, xargs, netcat, echo

I am trying to devise a one-liner to send text to a simple echo server - but multiple connections in parallel. This is what I'm trying:

```
echo -e  A,B,C,D | xargs -d, -i -P 4 echo {} |  nc localhost 7000
```

However, it doesn't quite work.  The server receives four connections but no data ("null").

What is the correct xargs and netcat command here?

Answer (score 2):

This can be a bit more concise (and readble I say) if you like using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel 'echo {} | nc localhost 7000' ::: A B C D
```

Or even:

```
parallel 'echo {} | nc localhost 7000' ::: {A..D}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `sh -c` to launch `xargs`:

`echo 'A,B,C,D' | xargs -d, -i -P 4 sh -c  'echo "{}" | nc localhost 7000'`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845863/how-to-use-in-an-xargs-command

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo -n` or you will get 5 connections instead four, one of them with no data. If in the server this is not checked, maybe it is causing your problem.

```
echo -n A,B,C,D | xargs -d, -I{} -P 4 -n 1 echo {} | nc localhost 7000
```

Moreover, using a netcat as listening server, it appears to work right:

```
zhen@sydow:~$ nc -l 7000
A
D
B
C
```

And also it seems to be parallel, I see out-of-order echo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat the echo, it is the default action of xargs. This one-liner serves as a quick self-contained test, but you can remove the test listener set up before the `&`

```
nc -l 7001 & echo  A B C D | xargs -P4 -n1 | nc localhost 7001
```

Results:

```
amit@deimos:~$ nc -l 7001 & echo A B C D | xargs -P4 -n1 | nc localhost 7001
[6] 7115
D
B
C
A
[6]   Done                    nc -l 7001
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For xargs

```
xargs -i -P 1200 nc -zvn {} 22 < textfile-with-hosts.txt
```

#### For parallel:

```
parallel -j200% -n1 -a textfile-with-hosts.txt nc -vz {} ::: 22
```